# Remove items from cart vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi 
I have create a shopping cart in vb.net, so far i can add items to cart but cant empty or remove items from cart. 
can anyone help me please?

this is the code I have so far:-

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

 <div id="mycart">
        <br />
    Your shopping cart:<br />
    <table style="width: 500px" align="center" cellspacing="0" 
            cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 286px; height: 153px">
                <asp:ListBox ID="lstCart" runat="server"
                    Width="267px" Height="135px">
                </asp:ListBox>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 153px">
                <asp:Button ID="btnRemove" runat="server"
                    Width="100px" Text="Remove Item" /><br /><br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnEmpty" runat="server" 
                    Width="100px" Text="Empty Cart" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnContinue" runat="server"
        PostBackUrl="~/index.aspx" Text="Continue Shopping" />&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="btnCheckOut" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/CheckOut.aspx" Text="Check Out" /><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

```
Partial Class MyCart
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load#
    Dim myCart = ShoppingCart.Instance
    lstCart.Items.Clear
    For Each item As CartItem In myCart.Items
        lstCart.Items.Add(item.Description)
    Next

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Should just be what you've alerady got minus the for each, ie:

```
lstCart.Items.Clear
```

Edit: just noticed your buttons in the HTML, to get them working you'll want something like :

```
    Protected Sub btnRemove_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
        lstCart.Items.Remove(lstCart.SelectedItem)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnEmpty_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEmpty.Click
        lstCart.Items.Clear 
    End Sub
```

Rene